# DBCP object created ... by the following code was never closed

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7, database-connection, jdbc-pool

we have troubles with not closed connections to DB in our application. I was trying everything, so I got to experimenting with DBCP.

Here are steps to reproduce problem:

1) I've installed on Windows:

- clean apache-tomcat-7.0.59
- Java 1.7.0_75

2) I've changed server.xml, I've added one Resource pointing to our DB

```
<Resource auth="Container" 
defaultTransactionIsolation="READ_COMMITTED" 
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" 
maxActive="20" 
initialSize="2" 
maxIdle="10" 
minIdle="2" 
maxWait="10000" 
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="60000" 
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000" 
testOnBorrow="true" 
validationInterval="30000"
removeAbandoned="true" 
removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
logAbandoned="true"
name="docpilotDB" 
password="xxx" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.1.1.1:1521:xe" 
username="zzz" 
validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"/>
```

3) I've added ojdbc6_g.jar to tomcat/lib directory

4) Then, I've created and deploy application with

```
<Context path="/drm">
  <ResourceLink global="docpilotDB" name="jdbc/docpilotDB" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>
```

and with one one test servlet

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Initial Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>net.docucom.csas.oms.drm_x.srvlt.InitialService</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

And the Servlet class is

```
public class InitialService extends GenericServlet {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InitialService.class);

    private DataSource ds;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        try {
            ds = getDataSource();
            run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
    }

    private DataSource getDataSource() throws SQLException {
        try {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/docpilotDB");
            return ds;
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to get DataSource", e);
        }
    }

    public void service(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

    private synchronized void run() throws Exception {
        log.info("InitialService: start");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            log.info("InitialService: counter=" + i);
            Thread.sleep(100);
            doSelect();
        }
        log.info("InitialService: end");
    }

    synchronized public Connection connect() throws Exception {
        int result = -1;
        log.debug("connect(): start");

        Connection con = null;

        try {
            con = ds.getConnection();
            log.debug("connect(): got connection " + con.getClass().getName());
            log.debug("connect(): " + DriverManager.getDriver(ds.getConnection().getMetaData().getURL()).getClass());
            result = 0;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            log.error("connect() Error!", e);
            con = null;
            return con;
        }
        log.debug("connect(): result=" + result);
        return con;
    }

    synchronized public int close(Connection con) throws Exception {
        int result = -1;
        log.debug("close(): start");

        if (con != null) {
            log.debug("con.close();");
            con.close();
            log.debug("con.isClosed=" + con.isClosed());
            con = null;
        }
        result = 0;
        log.debug("close(): result=" + result);
        return result;
    }

    public synchronized void doSelect() throws Exception {
        log.debug("doSelect(): start");
        Connection con  = null;
        //ResultSet res = null;
        try{
            con = connect();

            // if (stmt == null) {
            // stmt = con.createStatement();
            // }
            //
            // res = this.stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM [DRM_OMS].[dbo].[Vat]");
            // while (res.next()) {
            // String Id = res.getString("id");
            // String DPH = res.getString("DPH");
            //
            // }
            //
            // res.close();
            // res = null;
        } finally {
            if (con != null){
                close(con);
            }
        }

        log.debug("doSelect(): end");

    }

}
```

There is no other customization on the tomcat server.

The log looks pritty nice until the 20.iteration

```
11:12:58.850  INFO   InitialService: start
11:12:58.856  INFO   InitialService: counter=0
11:12:58.957 DEBUG   doSelect(): start
11:12:58.957 DEBUG   connect(): start
11:12:59.056 DEBUG   connect(): got connection org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
11:12:59.079 DEBUG   connect(): class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
11:12:59.079 DEBUG   connect(): result=0
11:12:59.079 DEBUG   close(): start
11:12:59.079 DEBUG   con.close();
11:12:59.079 DEBUG   con.isClosed=true
11:12:59.079 DEBUG   close(): result=0
11:12:59.080 DEBUG   doSelect(): end
11:12:59.080  INFO   InitialService: counter=1
11:12:59.180 DEBUG   doSelect(): start
11:12:59.180 DEBUG   connect(): start
11:12:59.205 DEBUG   connect(): got connection org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
11:12:59.761 DEBUG   connect(): class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
11:12:59.761 DEBUG   connect(): result=0
11:12:59.762 DEBUG   close(): start
11:12:59.762 DEBUG   con.close();
11:12:59.762 DEBUG   con.isClosed=true
11:12:59.762 DEBUG   close(): result=0
11:12:59.762 DEBUG   doSelect(): end
11:12:59.762  INFO   InitialService: counter=2
11:12:59.863 DEBUG   doSelect(): start
11:12:59.863 DEBUG   connect(): start
11:12:59.884 DEBUG   connect(): got connection org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
11:13:00.524 DEBUG   connect(): class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
11:13:00.524 DEBUG   connect(): result=0
11:13:00.524 DEBUG   close(): start
11:13:00.524 DEBUG   con.close();
11:13:00.524 DEBUG   con.isClosed=true
11:13:00.524 DEBUG   close(): result=0
11:13:00.524 DEBUG   doSelect(): end
11:13:00.524  INFO   InitialService: counter=3
11:13:00.624 DEBUG   doSelect(): start
11:13:00.624 DEBUG   connect(): start
11:13:00.679 DEBUG   connect(): got connection org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
11:13:01.315 DEBUG   connect(): class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
11:13:01.315 DEBUG   connect(): result=0
11:13:01.315 DEBUG   close(): start
11:13:01.316 DEBUG   con.close();
11:13:01.316 DEBUG   con.isClosed=true
11:13:01.316 DEBUG   close(): result=0
11:13:01.316 DEBUG   doSelect(): end
11:13:01.316  INFO   InitialService: counter=4
11:13:01.416 DEBUG   doSelect(): start
11:13:01.416 DEBUG   connect(): start
11:13:01.462 DEBUG   connect(): got connection org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
11:13:02.146 DEBUG   connect(): class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
11:13:02.146 DEBUG   connect(): result=0
11:13:02.146 DEBUG   close(): start
11:13:02.146 DEBUG   con.close();
11:13:02.146 DEBUG   con.isClosed=true
11:13:02.146 DEBUG   close(): result=0
11:13:02.146 DEBUG   doSelect(): end
11:13:02.147  INFO   InitialService: counter=5
11:13:02.247 DEBUG   doSelect(): start
11:13:02.247 DEBUG   connect(): start
11:13:02.289 DEBUG   connect(): got connection org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
11:13:02.984 DEBUG   connect(): class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
11:13:02.984 DEBUG   connect(): result=0
11:13:02.984 DEBUG   close(): start
11:13:02.984 DEBUG   con.close();
11:13:02.984 DEBUG   con.isClosed=true
11:13:02.984 DEBUG   close(): result=0
11:13:02.984 DEBUG   doSelect(): end
11:13:02.984  INFO   InitialService: counter=6
11:13:03.084 DEBUG   doSelect(): start
11:13:03.084 DEBUG   connect(): start
11:13:03.118 DEBUG   connect(): got connection org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
11:13:03.447 DEBUG   connect(): class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
11:13:03.447 DEBUG   connect(): result=0
11:13:03.447 DEBUG   close(): start
11:13:03.447 DEBUG   con.close();
11:13:03.447 DEBUG   con.isClosed=true
11:13:03.447 DEBUG   close(): result=0
11:13:03.447 DEBUG   doSelect(): end
11:13:03.447  INFO   InitialService: counter=7
11:13:03.547 DEBUG   doSelect(): start
11:13:03.547 DEBUG   connect(): start
11:13:03.566 DEBUG   connect(): got connection org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
11:13:03.804 DEBUG   connect(): class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
11:13:03.804 DEBUG   connect(): result=0
11:13:03.804 DEBUG   close(): start
11:13:03.804 DEBUG   con.close();
11:13:03.804 DEBUG   con.isClosed=true
11:13:03.804 DEBUG   close(): result=0
11:13:03.805 DEBUG   doSelect(): end
11:13:03.805  INFO   InitialService: counter=8
11:13:03.906 DEBUG   doSelect(): start
11:13:03.906 DEBUG   connect(): start
11:13:03.927 DEBUG   connect(): got connection org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
11:13:04.163 DEBUG   connect(): class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
11:13:04.164 DEBUG   connect(): result=0
11:13:04.164 DEBUG   close(): start
11:13:04.164 DEBUG   con.close();
11:13:04.164 DEBUG   con.isClosed=true
11:13:04.164 DEBUG   close(): result=0
11:13:04.164 DEBUG   doSelect(): end
11:13:04.164  INFO   InitialService: counter=9
11:13:04.265 DEBUG   doSelect(): start
11:13:04.265 DEBUG   connect(): start
11:13:04.282 DEBUG   connect(): got connection org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
11:13:04.517 DEBUG   connect(): class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
11:13:04.518 DEBUG   connect(): result=0
11:13:04.518 DEBUG   close(): start
11:13:04.518 DEBUG   con.close();
11:13:04.518 DEBUG   con.isClosed=true
11:13:04.518 DEBUG   close(): result=0
11:13:04.518 DEBUG   doSelect(): end
11:13:04.518  INFO   InitialService: counter=10
11:13:04.618 DEBUG   doSelect(): start
11:13:04.618 DEBUG   connect(): start
11:13:04.643 DEBUG   connect(): got connection org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
11:13:04.876 DEBUG   connect(): class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
11:13:04.876 DEBUG   connect(): result=0
11:13:04.876 DEBUG   close(): start
11:13:04.876 DEBUG   con.close();
11:13:04.876 DEBUG   con.isClosed=true
11:13:04.876 DEBUG   close(): result=0
11:13:04.876 DEBUG   doSelect(): end
11:13:04.876  INFO   InitialService: counter=11
11:13:04.977 DEBUG   doSelect(): start
11:13:04.977 DEBUG   connect(): start
11:13:04.993 DEBUG   connect(): got connection org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
11:13:05.246 DEBUG   connect(): class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
11:13:05.246 DEBUG   connect(): result=0
11:13:05.247 DEBUG   close(): start
11:13:05.247 DEBUG   con.close();
11:13:05.247 DEBUG   con.isClosed=true
11:13:05.247 DEBUG   close(): result=0
11:13:05.247 DEBUG   doSelect(): end
11:13:05.247  INFO   InitialService: counter=12
11:13:05.348 DEBUG   doSelect(): start
11:13:05.348 DEBUG   connect(): start
11:13:05.371 DEBUG   connect(): got connection org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
11:13:05.639 DEBUG   connect(): class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
11:13:05.639 DEBUG   connect(): result=0
11:13:05.640 DEBUG   close(): start
11:13:05.640 DEBUG   con.close();
11:13:05.640 DEBUG   con.isClosed=true
11:13:05.640 DEBUG   close(): result=0
11:13:05.640 DEBUG   doSelect(): end
11:13:05.640  INFO   InitialService: counter=13
11:13:05.740 DEBUG   doSelect(): start
11:13:05.740 DEBUG   connect(): start
11:13:05.760 DEBUG   connect(): got connection org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
11:13:06.002 DEBUG   connect(): class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
11:13:06.003 DEBUG   connect(): result=0
11:13:06.003 DEBUG   close(): start
11:13:06.003 DEBUG   con.close();
11:13:06.003 DEBUG   con.isClosed=true
11:13:06.003 DEBUG   close(): result=0
11:13:06.003 DEBUG   doSelect(): end
11:13:06.003  INFO   InitialService: counter=14
11:13:06.105 DEBUG   doSelect(): start
11:13:06.105 DEBUG   connect(): start
11:13:06.121 DEBUG   connect(): got connection org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
11:13:06.348 DEBUG   connect(): class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
11:13:06.348 DEBUG   connect(): result=0
11:13:06.348 DEBUG   close(): start
11:13:06.348 DEBUG   con.close();
11:13:06.348 DEBUG   con.isClosed=true
11:13:06.348 DEBUG   close(): result=0
11:13:06.348 DEBUG   doSelect(): end
11:13:06.348  INFO   InitialService: counter=15
11:13:06.448 DEBUG   doSelect(): start
11:13:06.448 DEBUG   connect(): start
11:13:06.467 DEBUG   connect(): got connection org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
11:13:06.747 DEBUG   connect(): class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
11:13:06.747 DEBUG   connect(): result=0
11:13:06.747 DEBUG   close(): start
11:13:06.747 DEBUG   con.close();
11:13:06.747 DEBUG   con.isClosed=true
11:13:06.747 DEBUG   close(): result=0
11:13:06.747 DEBUG   doSelect(): end
11:13:06.747  INFO   InitialService: counter=16
11:13:06.848 DEBUG   doSelect(): start
11:13:06.848 DEBUG   connect(): start
11:13:06.862 DEBUG   connect(): got connection org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
11:13:07.112 DEBUG   connect(): class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
11:13:07.112 DEBUG   connect(): result=0
11:13:07.112 DEBUG   close(): start
11:13:07.112 DEBUG   con.close();
11:13:07.112 DEBUG   con.isClosed=true
11:13:07.112 DEBUG   close(): result=0
11:13:07.112 DEBUG   doSelect(): end
11:13:07.112  INFO   InitialService: counter=17
11:13:07.214 DEBUG   doSelect(): start
11:13:07.214 DEBUG   connect(): start
11:13:07.233 DEBUG   connect(): got connection org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
11:13:07.477 DEBUG   connect(): class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
11:13:07.479 DEBUG   connect(): result=0
11:13:07.479 DEBUG   close(): start
11:13:07.479 DEBUG   con.close();
11:13:07.479 DEBUG   con.isClosed=true
11:13:07.479 DEBUG   close(): result=0
11:13:07.480 DEBUG   doSelect(): end
11:13:07.480  INFO   InitialService: counter=18
11:13:07.580 DEBUG   doSelect(): start
11:13:07.580 DEBUG   connect(): start
11:13:07.603 DEBUG   connect(): got connection org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
11:13:07.866 DEBUG   connect(): class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
11:13:07.867 DEBUG   connect(): result=0
11:13:07.867 DEBUG   close(): start
11:13:07.867 DEBUG   con.close();
11:13:07.867 DEBUG   con.isClosed=true
11:13:07.867 DEBUG   close(): result=0
11:13:07.867 DEBUG   doSelect(): end
11:13:07.867  INFO   InitialService: counter=19
11:13:07.968 DEBUG   doSelect(): start
11:13:07.968 DEBUG   connect(): start
11:13:07.991 DEBUG   connect(): got connection org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
11:13:18.001 ERROR   connect() Error!
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1171) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.AbandonedObjectPool.borrowObject(AbandonedObjectPool.java:79) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:7.0.59]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:114) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:7.0.59]
    at net.docucom.csas.oms.drm_x.srvlt.InitialService.connect(InitialService.java:68) [InitialService.class:na]
    at net.docucom.csas.oms.drm_x.srvlt.InitialService.doSelect(InitialService.java:99) [InitialService.class:na]
    at net.docucom.csas.oms.drm_x.srvlt.InitialService.run(InitialService.java:54) [InitialService.class:na]
    at net.docucom.csas.oms.drm_x.srvlt.InitialService.init(InitialService.java:30) [InitialService.class:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5262) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5550) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877) [catalina.jar:7.0.59]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]
11:13:18.001 DEBUG   doSelect(): end
11:13:18.001  INFO   InitialService: counter=20
11:13:18.102 DEBUG   doSelect(): start
11:13:18.102 DEBUG   connect(): start
```

and after abandoned timeout the console of tomcat is full of messages that DBCP is not closed.

```
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.AbandonedTrace$AbandonedObjectException: DBCP object created 2016-02-05 11:12:59 by the following code was never closed:
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.AbandonedTrace.setStackTrace(AbandonedTrace.java:139)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.AbandonedObjectPool.borrowObject(AbandonedObjectPool.java:81)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at net.docucom.csas.oms.drm_x.srvlt.InitialService.connect(InitialService.java:68)
        at net.docucom.csas.oms.drm_x.srvlt.InitialService.doSelect(InitialService.java:99)
        at net.docucom.csas.oms.drm_x.srvlt.InitialService.run(InitialService.java:54)
        at net.docucom.csas.oms.drm_x.srvlt.InitialService.init(InitialService.java:30)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5262)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5550)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.AbandonedTrace$AbandonedObjectException: DBCP object created 2016-02-05 11:12:59 by the following code was never closed:
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.AbandonedTrace.init(AbandonedTrace.java:90)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.AbandonedTrace.<init>(AbandonedTrace.java:73)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingDatabaseMetaData.<init>(DelegatingDatabaseMetaData.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.getMetaData(DelegatingConnection.java:345)
...................
```

Could someone help with this issue? There is no logic now, I'm only fighting with DBCP and connections via DataSource. I'm pretty sure, that I'm closing connections. It is clear in the Java code.

Why are the connections not closed?
Please help!

Kind regards and thank you for your time and help.

Martin M.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Did you find the solution @M.Mayer?

Comment: @Ryan any reason for opening a bounty on this old thread? For all we know, it could be a bug in DBCP itself and may have been fixed since. if you have any new info, please add.

Comment: I'm seeing very similar error messages in a similar version of Tomcat and DBCP.  I thought this question matched my situation but @ShaneCoder spotted an extra getConnection call that is probably causing OP's problems.

Answer (score 2):

The logging is getting an extra connection each time through the loop:

```
        log.debug("connect(): " + DriverManager.getDriver(ds.getConnection().getMetaData().getURL()).getClass());
```

Each time this runs, it gets a connection from the datasource.  After 20 iterations, the connection pool has 20 connections "in use".  Since `maxActive=20` the `DataSource` can't create another connection.  Hence the next call fails waiting for one of the 20 unused/unclosed connections to get closed.

The later exceptions are complaining about those connections that never got closed.

The logging line should use the connection already retrieved.

```
        log.debug("connect(): " + DriverManager.getDriver(con.getMetaData().getURL()).getClass());
```